# Is natural resin + beeswax + oil suitable as a wood finish?

Tags: finishing

I usually apply raw coconut oil to my wooden stuff once a year. I do this because I want to keep things as natural as possible: I like the original color of wood and I dislike varnishes and finishes that contain ingredients I do not understand how they are processed.

I wanted to try a finish based on beeswax and oil (either coconut, olive or canola oil). Unfortunately where I live, beeswax is hard to find.

The other day I came across a natural hair removal wax which contains only beeswax and natural resin (see photo below).

[image: wax]

I know that neither oil nor beeswax will negatively affect the wood, but what about the natural resin in this wax?

Note that the product label does not state what are the beeswax and natural resin proportions...

Comment: I can't answer this definitively but at a guess no, you don't want to use this. The resin component is there specifically to be increase what's known as 'tack', so there's a good likelihood that it will make the wood sticky!

Comment: What "wooden stuff" are you treating with coconut oil currently? I'd also like to suggest some alternatives to coconut oil, but they may not be better choices if you're treating wooden kitchen utensils rather than a piece of furniture.

Comment: @Graphus I started treating my wooden kitchen utensils with coconut oil and it worked so well that I gave it a shot on my furniture. I discovered that it worked well for that too: nice smell, not sticky at all, and protects from liquid stains up to some degree. The inconvenience is that, as mentioned before, I have to reapply coconut oil every once in a while... That being said, I am open to suggestions :)

Comment: For furniture items I'd recommend switching to a drying or semi-drying oil. Linseed oil is the classic one in Western woodworking (usually the "boiled" variety although this is no longer how it's made), but tung oil is an option now too. Walnut oil is also a possibility if neither of the previous are easily obtainable. Because these oils 'dry' they build up in the surface wood fibres with subsequent coats and can make a very decent finish.

Comment: If you do need protection from liquids on specific surfaces polyurethane varnish is hard to beat and a varnished surface blends in with adjacent oiled surfaces well since varnish has an oil base. There's not much to be scared about using varnish, it can be thinned and applied much like oils are by wiping on and wiping away all excess making it very easy to get a smooth, drip-free result.

Comment: I would recommend staying away from oils like olive oil as they go rancid!

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with the look of (and maintenance of) coconut oil then you will be happy with the bees wax/natural resin as well. It is unlikely, but the resin may darken the wood a tiny bit more then straight oil (most folks won't see a difference).

Also depending on the resin, the resin may cause the wax to buff to a shinier sheen. (In fact, some folks use rosin just for this effect.) As always, I suggest testing on scrap to ensure you know what to expect. If you are not happy, the wax can be removed with a bit of effort and mineral spirits (or a similar solvent).